# Collecting data from nested lists and dictionaries without so many for/if statements

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've been working a lot with monday.com's API lately. Once I receive queried data, I retrieve specific pieces to check them with other values, manipulate them, etc. Due to the complexity of the query, I often find myself having to iterate through nested lists of dictionaries with values of more nested lists of dictionaries. It's fairly easy to iterate through them to find the exact information I am looking for, but I'd like to know if there are some better practices then using list comprehensions, or multiple `for`/`if` statements.

Lets use the below as an example. The goal is to find the "items" value id where the name is equal to the "groups" title after the second dash (`-`).

The first "groups" title to match is `2000 Foo Bar: Mapping`. That would return the id of `1234564130`.

The second "groups" title is `Computer 2023`. That would return the id of `1234564074`.

So on and so forth.

The code I have below works and is fast enough for my current situation, but I know that using double `for` loops can become quite slow (O(n²)). And I have 5 nested `for` loops.... I understand this question can be opinionated based, but are there some better methods for digging this specific information out?

```
{'data': {'boards': [{'groups': [{'title': '123456-G123456.00 - 2000 Foo Bar: Mapping', 'items_page': {'cursor': None, 'items': [{'id': '1234564130', 'name': '2000 Foo Bar: Mapping'}, {'id': '1234564156', 'name': '2000.5 - 2000.5 Ground Model'}]}}, {'title': '123456-R12345.00 - Computer 2023', 'items_page': {'cursor': None, 'items': [{'id': '1234564074', 'name': 'Computer 2023'}, {'id': '1234564096', 'name': '3000.1 - 3000.1 Veggies'}]}}, {'title': '123456-T12345.00 - Dodge - Design', 'items_page': {'cursor': None, 'items': [{'id': '1234564028', 'name': 'Dodge - Design'}, {'id': '1234564048', 'name': '-'}]}}, {'title': 'Group Title', 'items_page': {'cursor': None, 'items': [{'id': '1234563996', 'name': 'Task 1'}]}}]}]}, 'account_id': 123456}
```

```
query_group_id = f"""
{{
    boards (ids: {my_board_id}) {{
        groups {{
            title
            items_page (limit: 50) {{
                cursor
                items {{
                    id
                    name
                }}
            }}
        }}
    }}
}}
"""
data = {'query' : query_group_id}
r = requests.post(url=apiUrl, json=data, headers=headers)
r_dict = r.json()

group_board_info = r_dict['data']['boards'][0]['groups']

# This is absoluetly disgusting
for dictionary in group_board_info:
    for k,v in dictionary.items():
        if k == 'title':
            g_name = '-'.join(v.split('-')[2:]).lstrip() # Remove leading white space
        if k == "items_page":
            for k2, v2 in v.items():
                if k2 == 'items':
                    for dictionary2 in v2:
                        vals_list = list(dictionary2.values())
                        keys_list = list(dictionary2.keys())
                        for idx, key in enumerate(keys_list):
                            if key == 'id':
                                if vals_list[1] == g_name:
                                   create_subitem_for_item(vals_list[0], 'init')
```

**Edits**:

With the comments below and reconsideration, here is my new code. This is much easy to read, comprehend, and should be easy to integrated with other iteration methods. A colleague of mine suggested looking into `glom`.

```
for dictionary in group_board_info:
    items = dictionary['items_page']['items']
    for item in items:
        if '-'.join(dictionary['title'].split('-')[2:]).lstrip() == item['name']:
            create_subitem_for_item(item['id'], 'init')
```

Comment: Why do you iterate dictionaries when the whole point is you can look for the key in O(1) time?

Comment: Hopefully O(1).

Comment: @jarmod oops! Nice catch :D

Comment: Example: `dictionary["items_page"]["items"]`

Comment: @roganjosh Not sure I understand your question, but I am iterating over the dictionaries because there are more than one key I am trying to find a match to.

Comment: What's the point of `for idx, key in enumerate(keys_list): if key == 'id':`? `idx` and `key` are both unused. Maybe you wanted `if key in dictionary2`?

Comment: @roganjosh is saying there's no need to loop when you can just use lookups. Jarmod gave an example, and another one is `g_name = '-'.join(dictionary['title']...`. You only need to loop over the lists, `group_board_info` and `dictionary["items_page"]['items']`.

Comment: Another thing is, why are you using indexes on `vals_list`? I think you want to use the keys: `if dictionary2['name'] == g_name: ... dictionary2['id']`

Comment: Typo: I meant `if 'id' in dictionary2`, not `key`

Comment: I am understanding. Need some time to think it over. Will respond later. Thank you for the feedback and clarifying.

Comment: @wjandrea the comment concerning `enumerate(keys_list)`. I should not be enumerating that. I must have thought I needed that for something later down the road, but it should not be there. I did use the `key` in the next line, but as everyone has mentioned, I should be using lookups. I'll spend some more time with the suggestions and make necessary edits when I finish.

Comment: @wjandrea made some edits with some new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need all those loops, as discussed in the comments, since dicts support lookups.

An easier way to handle nested but uniform data is with [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)' [`json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html). It lets you just specify the path(s) to the data you want, then you get a table out (a DataFrame).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.json_normalize(
    r_dict['data']['boards'][0]['groups'],
    ['items_page', 'items'],
    ['title'])
print(df)
```

```
           id                          name                                      title
0  1234564130         2000 Foo Bar: Mapping  123456-G123456.00 - 2000 Foo Bar: Mapping
1  1234564156  2000.5 - 2000.5 Ground Model  123456-G123456.00 - 2000 Foo Bar: Mapping
2  1234564074                 Computer 2023           123456-R12345.00 - Computer 2023
3  1234564096       3000.1 - 3000.1 Veggies           123456-R12345.00 - Computer 2023
4  1234564028                Dodge - Design          123456-T12345.00 - Dodge - Design
5  1234564048                             -          123456-T12345.00 - Dodge - Design
6  1234563996                        Task 1                                Group Title
```

Then you can use Pandas' features like [vectorized string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods):

```
g_name = df['title'].str.split('-', n=2).str[2].str.lstrip()
print(g_name)
```

```
0    2000 Foo Bar: Mapping
1    2000 Foo Bar: Mapping
2            Computer 2023
3            Computer 2023
4           Dodge - Design
5           Dodge - Design
6                      NaN
Name: g_name, dtype: object
```

(`NaN` is used for [missing values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html).)

And you can [select](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) the elements you want:

```
result = df.loc[df['name'].eq(g_name), 'id']
print(result)
```

```
0    1234564130
2    1234564074
4    1234564028
Name: id, dtype: object
```

This selection (passed to `.loc`) means:

- rows where `name` equals `g_name` at the same position
- column `id`

Comment: Cool pandas solution! Appreciate the suggest, help, and detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

> *'... I'd like to know if there are some better practices then using list comprehensions, or multiple `for`/`if` statements. ...'*

Possibly; although, since the dictionaries are nested, I don't see any other practical solution.

> *'... The goal is to find the "items" value id where the name is equal to the "groups" title after the second dash (`-`). ...'*

Here is an example.

```py
groups = d['data']['boards'][0]['groups']
ids = []
for group in groups:
    title = group['title']
    for item in group['items_page']['items']:
    for item in group['items_page']['items']:
        if title.endswith(item['name']): ids.append(item['id'])
```

Output

```
['1234564130', '1234564074', '1234564028']
```

> *'... are there some better methods for digging this specific information out? ...'*

Try researching different texts.  I recommend both, *[O'Reilly Media](https://www.oreilly.com/)*, and *[No Starch Press](https://nostarch.com/)*.
Realistically though, if you're concerned with the performance of the query, choose a different *[data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures)*, and *design*.